# What are attributes?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Could anyone please clarify the defination of attribute?

for example, in the following code, what is an attribute:

```
request.setAttribute("ja",new foo.Employee());
```

Is the attribute in the above code an object of type foo.Employee(), or it is key/value pair, or it is actually "ja"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request attributes are values indexed by a key (in your case "ja") which are shared in the life of the request object. In Java **filter, servlet, jsp, include and forward** use same request object so for example you can *push* an object in a servlet and *pull* it in a JSP.

The same approach is for session and application scopes

Answer (score 1):

Request attributes are (or at least act like) a map of objects, in this case the key is "ja" and the value is a new foo.Employee.

The session, page, and application have the same data structure.

Answer (score 1):

From the servlet API specification:

> Attributes are objects associated with a request. Attributes may be set by the
>   container to express information that otherwise could not be expressed via the API,
>   or may be set by a servlet to communicate information to another servlet (via the
>   RequestDispatcher). **Only one attribute value may be associated with an attribute name**.

Answer (score 0):

Here an attribute is a custom piece of information (here a new foo.Employee) added to your request (in a Map,Object> . This information will last as long as this request is processed and it can be used later in the process, for example by a JSP.

Answer (score 0):

It's a key value pair
From the docs:
setAttribute

> public void
>   setAttribute(java.lang.String name,
>                            java.lang.Object o)
>
> ```
> Stores an attribute in this request. Attributes are reset between
> ```
>
> requests. This method is most often
>   used in conjunction with
>   RequestDispatcher.
>
> ```
> Attribute names should follow the same conventions as package names.
> ```
>
> Names beginning with java.*, javax.*,
>   and com.sun.*, are reserved for use by
>   Sun Microsystems.
>       If the value passed in is null, the effect is the same as calling
>   removeAttribute(java.lang.String).